# sed switch the order of first and last word

Tags: regex, sed

I am trying to use sed to switch the order of the first and last word in a sentence, since I don't think I understand how "greedy" regular expression is in this case. I failed miserably just for a sentence of three words.

```
$ echo hello world mike | sed 's/\([a-z]*\).* \([a-z]*\).*/\2 \1/'
mike hello
```

Why the output is not "world hello mike"?
Some extra information that might be helpful.

1. \1 \2 are the first and second regular expression matches
2. I was following a [tutorial here](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-4).

My final goal is to switch the order of the first and last word in a sentence regardless of how many words there are in there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You didn't include the `hello` part as one of your capture groups, so it doesn't get output.  Try:

```
$ sed -E 's/([a-z]+) (.+) ([a-z]+)/\3 \2 \1/' <<< "hello world mike"
mike world hello
$ sed -E 's/([a-z]+) (.+) ([a-z]+)/\3 \2 \1/' <<< "hello world foo bar baz mike"
mike world foo bar baz hello
```

(Note: I also removed your [useless use of echo](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html#echo).)

You can also replace the `[a-z]` with `[[:alpha:]]` to handle capital letters, too:

```
$ sed -E 's/([[:alpha:]]+) (.+) ([[:alpha:]]+)/\3 \2 \1/' <<< "Hello world Mike"
Mike world Hello
```

Comment: Good use of `[[:alpha:]]`. You do assume that the first non-alpha character is a space though. What if it's a tab instead... Why not capture "everything" in the second group, and leave out the spaces in the substitution string: `s/([[:alpha:]]+)(.*)([[:alpha:]])/\3\2\1/`?

Comment: @Floris, OP's post had spaces, and I just wanted to make it easier to read.

Answer (score 4):

An other `awk` version

```
echo hello world mike | awk '{s=$1;$1=$NF;$NF=s}1'
mike world hello
```

Just swapping last and first filed should do the job.

Comment: +1.  This is the "right" way to solve the problem; sed probably isn't the appropriate tool.

Comment: @CarlNorum it's probably OK, but compared to the sed solutions or the awk solution posted by sputnik this one does have the possible negative (and probably unexpected by the OP) side-effect of changing all white space between the words in the middle of the sentence to single blank chars.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ echo "hello world mike" | sed -r 's/([^ ]+)(.* )([^ ]+)/\3\2\1/'
mike world hello
$ echo "this is a simple sentence" | sed -r 's/([^ ]+)(.+ )([^ ]+)/\3\2\1/'
sentence is a simple this
```

or in older seds that only support BREs, not EREs:

```
$ echo "hello world mike" | sed 's/\([^ ]*\)\(.* \)\([^ ]*\)/\3\2\1/'
mike world hello
$ echo "this is a simple sentence" | sed 's/\([^ ]*\)\(.* \)\([^ ]*\)/\3\2\1/'
sentence is a simple this
```

Answer (score 1):

With [awk](/questions/tagged/awk)  :

```
$ echo 'hello world mike' | awk '{v1=$1;v2=$NF;$1=$NF="";print v2, $0, v1}'
mike  world  hello
```

Comment: +1 for a good solution that uses awk while preserving inter-word spacing but lose the commas in the `print` so you don't add unnecessary OFS chars.

Answer (score 1):

You are asking to swap the first and last word on the line - so you need to make sure you capture those (and not the first and second word, as many of the above answers do).

```
echo "hello cruel and unkind world" | sed 's/^\([^ ]*\) \(.*\) \([^ ]*\)$/\3 \2 \1/'
```

will result in

```
world cruel and unkind hello
```

Here is how it works:

```
^\([^ ]*\)  - starting at the beginning of the line (^), find as many non-space characters as you can (stops at first space)
              note - depending on the flavor of sed you use, there are special symbols to map "a non whitespace, e.g. \S
            - the next space is matched but not captured
\(.*\)      - capture "everything" after this, until...
 \([^ ]*\)$ - a space followed by all non-space characters followed by the end of string
```

When you then output the three capture groups in reverse order, with a space in between, you get exactly what you were asking for.

Answer (score 1):

A sed command with a word boundary:

```
sed 's/\([A-Za-z]\+\)\(.\+\)\b\([A-Za-z]\+\)/\3\2\1/'
```

or in extended mode:

```
sed -r 's/([A-Za-z]+)(.+)\b([A-Za-z]+)/\3\2\1/'
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use another approach, like `split()` of a more powerful language, but for [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) you have to group all the content between both edge words:

```
echo hello world mike | sed 's/\([a-z]*\)\(.*\) \([a-z]*\).*/\3\2 \1/'
```

It yields:

```
mike world hello
```

Comment: @Floris: Correct, but I didn't warn of doing a robust command, simply fixed what he had wrong. I would not use `sed` for this. I guess it's a dummy example and he will know to adapt it accordingly for more complex data.